# p tag inside of a div tag

Tags: html, css

This is a two part problem. The first part is I want the image fade and the text fade to happen at the same time (on a hover over).

The second part is, I thought if I had the `<p>` tag inside of the `<div>` then it would "inherit" (I may not be using the term properly) the div properties. The text is supposed to remain fixed center of the image so anytime the image resizes or moves it takes the text with it.

Clearly neither one of those things are happening.

```css
.image-wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
}
.image-wrapper p:hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="fade" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
  <p>This text here</p>
</div>
```

[Here is a link just in case](https://jsfiddle.net/conder/1wdvhr45/)

Comment: Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/16k7r5m8/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

> 1. The first part is I want the image fade and the text fade to happen at the same time (on a hover over).

For this to happen, add `hover` to `image-wrapper` rather than individually to `p` and the `img` like the below for instance:

```
.image-wrapper:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .fade {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

> 2. The text is supposed to remain fixed center of the image so anytime
>      the image resizes or moves it takes the text with it.

For this you can use the `transform` to center align the text over the image responsively.

```
.image-wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

snippet below:

```css
.image-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  }

.image-wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.image-wrapper:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

}
.image-wrapper:hover .fade {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="fade" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
  <p>This text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Conde please let me know your thoughts on this? Please upvote / mark as correct if you found the answer helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @kikkuz This was perfect thank you! ..quick question so first you created a container with the div and then called the properties to the p tag from there? Why doesn't it work the other way? like how I had it. (Im sure theres a "law/rule" or something Im missing. or if there is an article(s) you can direct me too so I know the things I did wrong Id greatly appreciate it!

Comment: As you need both the `p` and the `img` to `transition` on `hover`, you should give hover to the parent wrapper rather than to the children `p` and `fade`, otherwise if you hover over image, you won't see the `p` and vice versa. Hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

for first one you can use like that

```
.image-wrapper:hover{
  opacity :0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both 1.) and 2.) - Try this code:**

---

HTML:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="fade" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <p class="fade">This text here</p>
</div>
```

Adding the `class="fade"` to the `<p>` will make the transition smoothly for the text as well.

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper p {
    display: none;
    color: #F00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
}

.image-wrapper p:hover, .image-wrapper:hover p {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    opacity: 100;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

// When either hovering the p or the image, apply the transition.

.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```